# "D3D12 ERROR: ID3D12Device::CreateComputePipelineState: Root Signature doesn't match Compute Shader..." where is the mistake in my code?

Tags: c++, directx, directx-12, directcompute

The full error in the debug output is:

"D3D12 ERROR: ID3D12Device::CreateComputePipelineState: Root Signature doesn't match Compute Shader: Shader SRV descriptor range (RegisterSpace=0, NumDescriptors=1, BaseShaderRegister=0) is not fully bound in root signature"

Which indicates that there's a problem with how I created the SRV/bound it to the root signature, but I'm unsure what exactly I did wrong.  I'm going to try and paste the minimally necessary code here:

```
void Dc12DxbcHelper::CreateComputePipelineState(
    _In_ ID3D12Device* pDevice,
    _In_ ID3D12RootSignature* pRootSignature,
    _In_reads_bytes_(length) const void* shader,
    size_t length,
    UINT nodeMask,
    D3D12_PIPELINE_STATE_FLAGS flags,
    _COM_Outptr_ ID3D12PipelineState** ppPipelineState)
{
    DxbcReader reader(
        reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t*>(shader),
        length);

    DC12::CreateComputePipelineState(
        pDevice,
        pRootSignature,
        reader.get_Shader(),
        reader.get_Length(),
        nodeMask,
        flags,
        ppPipelineState);
}
```

...

```
void DC12::CreateRootSignature(
    _In_ ID3D12Device* pDevice,
    _In_reads_opt_(numParameters) const D3D12_ROOT_PARAMETER* pParameters,
    UINT numParameters,
    _COM_Outptr_ ID3D12RootSignature** ppRootSignature)
{
    D3D12_ROOT_SIGNATURE_DESC rootSignatureDesc =
    {
        numParameters, // NumParameters
        pParameters, // pParameters
        0, // NumStaticSamplers
        nullptr, // pStaticSamplers
        D3D12_ROOT_SIGNATURE_FLAG_NONE, // Flags
    };

    SafeComPointer<ID3DBlob> blob;

    SafeComPointer<ID3DBlob> errorBlob;

    HRESULT hr = ::D3D12SerializeRootSignature(
        &rootSignatureDesc,
        D3D_ROOT_SIGNATURE_VERSION_1,
        blob.GetAddressOf(),
        errorBlob.GetAddressOf());

    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        std::string errorString(ERROR_MESSAGE);

        if (errorBlob)
        {
            errorString.append(": ");

            errorString.append(
                reinterpret_cast<char*>(
                    errorBlob->GetBufferPointer()),
                errorBlob->GetBufferSize());
        }

        throw std::system_error(
            hr,
            HRESULT_error_category(),
            errorString);
    }

    CHR(pDevice->CreateRootSignature(
        0,
        blob->GetBufferPointer(),
        blob->GetBufferSize(),
        IID_PPV_ARGS(ppRootSignature)));
}
```

...

```
        CreateWithSrv(
            _In_ const uint8_t threadGroupLog2,
            _In_ const uint32_t stagingWriteBufferSize,
            _In_ const uint32_t shaderResourceViewCount,
            _In_ const uint32_t unorderedAccessViewCount,
            _In_ const uint32_t stagingReadBufferCount)
        {

            ...

            // create & assign srv

            DC12::CreateDescriptorHeap(
                this->device.Get(),
                1,
                D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_HEAP_FLAG_NONE,
                0,
                this->srvDescriptor.GetAddressOf());

            DC12::CreateShaderResourceView(
                this->device.Get(),
                this->srvDescriptor.Get(),
                0,
                shaderResourceViewCount,
                this->srvBuffer.GetAddressOf());

            // create & assign uav

            DC12::CreateDescriptorHeap(
                this->device.Get(),
                1,
                D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_HEAP_FLAG_NONE,
                0,
                this->uavDescriptor.GetAddressOf());

            DC12::CreateUnorderedAccessView(
                this->device.Get(),
                this->uavDescriptor.Get(),
                0,
                unorderedAccessViewCount,
                this->uavBuffer.GetAddressOf());

            ...

        }
```

...

```
        class ROOT_PARAMETER_SRV
            : public D3D12_ROOT_PARAMETER
        {
        public:
            ROOT_PARAMETER_SRV(
                UINT shaderRegister)
            {
                this->ParameterType =
                    D3D12_ROOT_PARAMETER_TYPE_SRV;

                this->Descriptor =
                {
                    shaderRegister, // ShaderRegister
                    0, // RegisterSpace,
                };

                this->ShaderVisibility =
                    D3D12_SHADER_VISIBILITY_ALL;
            }
        };
```

...

```
Dc12HasherImpl::CreateWithSrv(
    CryptoNightDcHelper::ThreadGroupLog2,
    this->SrvSimdCount * sizeof(simd),
    this->SrvSimdCount,
    count,
    MaxUAVReadSizeSimd);

D3D12_ROOT_PARAMETER rootParameters[] =
{
    DC12::ROOT_PARAMETER_32BIT_CONSTANTS(0, 3),
    DC12::ROOT_PARAMETER_CBV(1),
    DC12::ROOT_PARAMETER_CBV(2),
    DC12::ROOT_PARAMETER_SRV(3),
    DC12::ROOT_PARAMETER_UAV(4),
};

DC12::CreateRootSignature(
    this->device.Get(),
    rootParameters,
    _countof(rootParameters),
    this->rootSignature.GetAddressOf());

D3D12_PIPELINE_STATE_FLAGS computePipelineStateFlags =
    D3D12_PIPELINE_STATE_FLAG_NONE;

Dc12DxbcHelper::CreateComputePipelineState(
    this->device.Get(),
    this->rootSignature.Get(),
    shaderBytecode,
    shaderBytecodeLength,
    0,
    computePipelineStateFlags,
    this->preKeccakShader.GetAddressOf());
```

Incidentally, this runs without errors through this point if I comment out all the SRV-specific stuff.  If there's something else you need for me to post here to better diagnose the issue, I can try to provide it.

edit:
relevant bit of the shader DX Asm:

```
...
dcl_constantbuffer cb0[1], immediateIndexed
dcl_constantbuffer cb1[13], immediateIndexed
dcl_constantbuffer cb2[1], immediateIndexed
dcl_resource_structured t0, 16
dcl_uav_structured u0, 16
...
```

Comment: You haven't shown your shader code, so I'm only guessing, but it sounds like you've not bound a resource in your shader to a definition in the root signature.

Comment: That sounds unlikely, unless I'm misunderstanding something.  Just in case, I've c/p'ed some of the declarations in shader code in the edit.